# Azure local disk - where'd it go? (Linux VM)

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

The Azure VM table...

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-2

...says that, for example, a Medium Instance comes with 490GB of local storage.  So I was expecting the usual 30GB Azure BLOB OS disk, and then a 490GB /mnt/resource.

But no:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       28G  1.7G   25G   7% /
tmpfs                 1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   68M  392M  15% /boot
/dev/sdb1             133G  188M  126G   1% /mnt/resource
```

That's on the CentOS image, but it's the same for other images.

Am i missing something?  I don't see the space in a volume group or anything, and there are no sd* devices that aren't mounted.

Comment: This is included in your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866493/in-an-azure-linux-vm-what-persists-what-disk-is-charged-for/12874671#12874671.  You are asking about the local storage that is described in the Cloud Services section, but you are using the Virtual Machines feature.  If you notice in the tables in the VM feature section of the page you reference above it mentions nothing about the local storage.

Comment: All Windows Azure IaaS VMs come with two disks - an OS disk backed by a VHD persisted in Windows Azure Blob storage and a temp disk physically attached to the hosting server. This temp disk is truly ephemeral and any contents on it will be lost if the VM is deallocated (shutdown on the portal or API) or moved for server healing. For Linux VMs this temporary disk /dev/sdb.

Answer (score 0):

Neil Mackenzie's answer in the comments appears to be correct

> All Windows Azure IaaS VMs come with two disks - an OS disk backed by a VHD
>   persisted in Windows Azure Blob storage and a temp disk physically
>   attached to the hosting server. This temp disk is truly ephemeral and
>   any contents on it will be lost if the VM is deallocated (shutdown on
>   the portal or API) or moved for server healing. For Linux VMs this
>   temporary disk /dev/sdb.

I found this link to corroborate:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/07/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

Comment: is it safe to have swapfile  on that tmp disk? wont lose data when resizing Vm ( whatever is on the swap...?)