# Azure Ubuntu: Why is the temp drive mounted to /mnt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure

In Azure, I have installed a Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. After the first boot, I got the following output from `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G  879M   27G   4% /
udev            328M   12K  328M   1% /dev
tmpfs           135M  248K  135M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            337M     0  337M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1        20G  172M   19G   1% /mnt
```

According to [Azure local disk - where'd it go? (Linux VM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876947/azure-local-disk-whered-it-go-linux-vm), `/dev/sdb1` is the local temp disk.

What is the reason that the temp disk is automatically mounted to `/mnt`, and is it possible to change the mount point of `/dev/sdb1`?

edit:
This is how the fstab looks after installing, so I can't see how to change the mount point of `/dev/sdb1`

```
UUID=2779695b-335b-4e4f-8c2c-60ce40546b10       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to change the mount point of /dev/sdb1 if you have the windows azure agent installed.  In RHEL/centos systems, the configuration file is located in /etc/waagent.conf

For RHEL/centos this agent is provided by the openlogic Repo and is titled: WALinuxAgent.noarch                    2.0.11-1                        @OpenLogic

Comment: Yes, all Azure VMs have the agent installed, you can change it in /etc/waagent.conf: *ResourceDisk.MountPoint=/mnt*. Other distros mount in /mnt/resource. The agent mounts during startup, an "exception" would be CoreOS images which use systemd and changing the mount point requires something like [this](http://bureado.com/2015/02/01/rebasing-coreos-for-ephemeral-cloud-storage/)

Comment: For CoreOS the file is actually located at /usr/share/oem/waagent.conf

Comment: should i also change the record in /etc/fstab in ubuntu vm in Azure ?